# Expo fontello don't load

Tags: react-native, expo, fontello, vector-icons

I'm trying to load a fontello icons in my project, but if I try to load in App.js, it send "false' and the app don't load:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import theme from "./src/globalStyles/theme";

import Routes from "./src/routes";

import {
  useFonts,
  Roboto_400Regular,
  Roboto_500Medium,
  Roboto_700Bold,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/roboto";

import { Fontello } from "./assets/fonts/fontello.ttf";

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Roboto_400Regular,
    Roboto_500Medium,
    Roboto_700Bold,
    Fontello,
  });
  console.log(fontsLoaded)
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Routes />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

And if I comment the line with Fontello, it load the app but I got the following error:
**fontFamily "fontello" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.**

**If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.**

**If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `expo-font`

```
expo install expo-font
```

Create a folder called `hooks` where you `App.js` is located.

Inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js` paste this code

`useFonts.js`

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { Roboto_400Regular } from '@expo-google-fonts/roboto';

const useFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    Roboto: Roboto_400Regular,
    Fontello: require('../assets/fonts/fontello.ttf'),
    // All Other Fonts
  });
};

export default useFonts;
```

Then in your `App.js` paste this code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

import theme from './src/globalStyles/theme';
import Routes from './src/routes';
import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts(); 
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)}
        onError={(error) => console.log(error)}
      />
    );
  }

   return (
     <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
       <Routes />
     </ThemeProvider>
   );
}
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/font-loading) Works on Android. Some bug in the web version.